# If $G$ is a group of order $2^nm$, where $m$ is odd and $(m-1)!<2^n$, show that $G$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

If $G$ is a group of order $2^nm$, where $m$ is odd and $(m-1)!<2^n$, show that $G$ is not simple.

I started out by trying to prove this using the Sylow theorem, but it led nowhere. I was able to prove this for the case $n=1$. Perhaps someone can generalize the following proof for any $n$:

Let $\pi:G\to S_G$ be the left-regular representation and let $x\in G$ be an element of order $2$. Since $\pi$ is injective, the restriction map
$$
\pi \mid_{H}:H=\langle x \rangle \to S_G
$$
is also injective.

Let $g\in G$. Then the $H$-orbit of $g$ is $\{ g,xg \}$, so that $\pi(x)$ is the product of $m$ disjoint $2$-cycles. But $m$ is odd, which implies $\pi(x)$ is an odd permutation. It follows that $\pi(G)$ is not a subgroup of $A_G$.

Now consider $\pi(G)A_G$, which is a subgroup of $S_G$ since $A_G$ is normal. I claim that $S_G=\pi(G)A_G$. To see this, observe that $S_G/A_G$ is cyclic of order $2$, generated by the class of $\pi(x)$. Then $\sigma\in S_G$ implies that 
$$
\sigma A_G = \pi(x)^s A_G
$$ 
for some $s$. Conclude that $\sigma\in \pi(G)A_G$ and $S_G=\pi(G)A_G$, as required.

Therefore,
$$
|S_G|=|\pi(G)S_G|=\frac{|\pi(G)||A_G|}{|\pi(G)\cap A_G|}
$$
and we see that $[\pi(G):\pi(G)\cap A_G]=2$, so that $G$ has a normal subgroup ($G$ is isomorphic to its image in $S_G$).

Can this proof be generalized?

Comment: Note that if $n=1$, then $m$ must also be 1 so the group is of order 2. $n$ must be $>1$.

Comment: Is $m$ assumed to be greater than $1$? If not there's a trivial case where it's false ($m=n=1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this relies heavily on the fact that $n=1$. Here is a general proof.

Suppose $P\leq G$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup. Then there is a homomorphism $\pi:G\to S_{m}$ induced by the action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $P$. If $G$ is simple then $\pi$ must be injective because it is not trivial. This means that
$$2^nm\leq m!$$
so
$$2^n\leq (m-1)!$$
But this contradicts the hypothesis that $(m-1)!<2^n$.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more explict about why $\pi$ is injective? If we had $g_ogH=g_o'gH$ for every $g$, why would $g_o=g'_o$? Could we conjure a non trivial normal group if we assume $g_o \not=g'_o$?

Comment: @Kadmos $G$ is simple so by definition it has no proper nontrivial normal subgroups.

Comment: @Kadmos Isomorphism theorem. If a homomorphism is not injective then its kernel is not trivial, so it must be a normal subgroup. If the homomorphism is not trivial then the kernel is not the whole group. So it would be a proper normal subgroup if the isomorphism is nontrivial but not injective.

Comment: +1, thank you. If it weren't injective, the kernel would be a non trivial normal subgroup.